# MS Access auto fill form not filling currency

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, autofill

I have a form where the user selects an InventoryID from a combo box, and it auto-fills the other information (setID and RentalRate).  It will fill the setID, but will not fill the RentalRate. In the table it is based on, RentalRate is formatted to currency.

The internal select query for cboInvnetoryID has the following columns:
0. record ID (autonumber)

1. Inventory ID (text)
2. setID (text)
3. RentalRte (currency)

This is my VBA for the autofill:

```
Private Sub cboInventoryID_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtSetID.Value = Me.cboInventoryID.Column(2)
Me.txtRentalRate.Value = Me.cboInventoryID.Column(3)
End Sub
```

Any thoughts on why the RentalRate field is not auto-filling?

Answer (score 1):

A combobox returns text only, so fill the rate column with string expressions, that can be converted to Currency:

```
RentalRateText = Str([RentalRte])
```

Use a query for this like:

```sql
Select [Inventory ID], SetId, Str([RentalRte]) As RentalRateText
From YourTable
Order By [Inventory ID]
```

Now, convert these to number:

```
Me!txtRentalRate.Value = Val(Me!.cboInventoryID.Column(3))
```

Also, I guess, `.Column(3)` should read `.Column(2)` as the column index is zero based.

Comment: I'm very, very new to all of this. Where would I add the string expressions?

Comment: I found where to put the string function.  It's getting closer, now I get a Run Time Error 2448 "you can't assign a value to this object", and it will display $0 not the actual value.  Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by converting to number for the second part?  Could you clarify?  Thank you!

Comment: Adding: when I debug, it points to:
Me.txtRentalRate.Value = Me.cboInventoryID.Column(3)
and when I hover it adds = Null

Comment: Adjust your query - see edited answer, please. The _Null_ is caused by (as mentioned) the fact, that the count is zero-based and you don't have 4 fields in the query. Use 2.

Answer (score 0):

There was quite a bit going on. For starters, I missed that my tables the form was based on were not normalized, so I fixed that.  I also had the column count confused, so the VBA was correct, I just had the column numbers flipped around.